# how to create new connection with redis on each request with username and password using spring data redis?

Tags: java, redis, multi-tenant, spring-data-redis, lettuce

I am using spring data redis to connect to standalone redis. I am using `LettuceConnectionFactory` to create initial connection with redis with default user but after connection has been established I want to connect to different user with redis on each request basically to achive ACL feature in redis.

I created instance of `LettuceConnectionFactory` object for initial startup of application with following code.

```java
    @Bean
    public RedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        LettucePoolingClientConfiguration clientConfiguration = LettucePoolingClientConfiguration.builder().poolConfig(new GenericObjectPoolConfig()).build();
        RedisStandaloneConfiguration redisStandaloneConfiguration = new RedisStandaloneConfiguration("localhost", 6379);
        LettuceConnectionFactory lettuceConnectionFactory = new LettuceConnectionFactory(redisStandaloneConfiguration, clientConfiguration);
        return new MultiTenantDatabaseConnection(redisStandaloneConfiguration, lettuceConnectionFactory);
    }
```

```java
public class MultiTenantDatabaseConnection extends LettuceConnectionFactory {

    private final LettuceConnectionFactory lettuceConnectionFactory;

    public MultiTenantDatabaseConnection(RedisConfiguration redisConfiguration, LettuceConnectionFactory lettuceConnectionFactory) {
        super(redisConfiguration);
        this.lettuceConnectionFactory = lettuceConnectionFactory;
    }

    @Override
    public RedisConnection getConnection() {
        String userName = "****";
        String password = "****";
        if (Objects.nonNull(TenantContext.getTenant().get())) {
           userName = TenantContext.getTenant().get().getUserId();
           password = TenantContext.getTenant().get().getPassword();
        }
        RedisURI localhost = RedisURI.create("localhost", 6379);
        localhost.setUsername(userName);
        localhost.setPassword(password.toCharArray());

        return new CustomLettuceConnection(2000, RedisClient.create(localhost));
    }
}
```

this code snippet is creating new instance of lettuce connection on each http request but I think I am not following framework pattern to create connection and I am not even using LettuceConnectionFactory object. I tried every implementation to create new connection with existing LettuceConnectionFactory object but I am getting nowhere.

**I am getting below warning with above code snippet**

```
2023-07-04 18:49:44.054  WARN 31175 --- [      Finalizer] i.l.c.resource.DefaultClientResources    : io.lettuce.core.resource.DefaultClientResources was not shut down properly, shutdown() was not called before it's garbage-collected. Call shutdown() or shutdown(long,long,TimeUnit)
```

**I tried below method also but I think this is also wrong**

```
    @Override
    public RedisConnection getConnection() {
        LettuceConnectionFactory lettuceConnectionFactory = new LettuceConnectionFactory(standaloneConfiguration);
        lettuceConnectionFactory.afterPropertiesSet();
        return lettuceConnectionFactory.getConnection();
    }
```